# Functions with Variable Numbers of Arguments: Outer Vector Product

Tags: function-construction, vector, variable

I am trying to write a function that takes a column vector of variable dimension as an input and returns the outer product matrix as an output.

What I have tried:

```
OuterVectorProduct[x__] := MatrixForm[Outer[Times, x, x]]
```

However, this obviously returns wrong results.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post an example of wrong result?

Comment: @kglr Having `MatrixForm` in the definition makes it a bit useless for further computation. Otherwise, its fine (except `x_` would be better than `x__`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that will get you started,

```
x = {x1, x2, x3};
y = {y1, y2};

(xy = KroneckerProduct[x, y]) // MatrixForm

(* get 3x2 matrix output *) 

(yx = KroneckerProduct[y, x]) // MatrixForm 

(* get 2x3 matrix output *)
```

The parentheses are important --- compare the `FullForm` of the resulting "matrix" if you leave them out.

Edit:

In answer to your specific Qn,

```
OuterVectorProduct[x_] := KroneckerProduct[x, x]
```

which will work for a vector `x` for any value of `Dimensions[x]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My issue is, though, that I am struggling with the variable nature of my arguments, not the syntax of the outer product.

Comment: Thank you for your help!